# How to change javaScript context in the content script of an extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My content.js script wont work if it can't run on the correct context, currently I have no idea how to change the context via js.

*content.js*

```js
chrome.runtime.connect();

console.log("Loaded");

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  const p = request[0]
  UPunkte = p
  UKokku = p

  const t = request[1]
  tehteidTasemeti = [0, Math.round(t/5), Math.round(t/5), Math.round(t/5), Math.round(t/5), Math.round(t/5)]
  console.log("Set"); // gets outputted
}
);
```

I need to change the variables UPunkte, UKokku and tehteidTasemeti, but I can't do so if I am not in the correct context.
The context I am trying to enter is called "sisufreim (nutimati.php)"

I have tried looking for similar topics, but the answers never really answered the question. I've also tried looking at documentations for the google API and the closest thing to what I think the solution is, is this thing called [script injection](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#functionality).
I am quite new to js and web development related stuff so I don't quite understand much of the vocabulary.